# Passing vectors members individually

Tags: graphics, clojure, polygon, seesaw

I am trying to pass a list of arguments to the `polygon` function:

```
(polygon [1 2] [3 4] [5 6])

(polygon pairs) ;;Throws exception
```

where pairs:

```
clojure.lang.LazySeq  ([2.2935636 48.8580886] [2.2933061 48.8582457] [2.2935366 48.8584053] [2.2935553 48.8583952] ...)
```

Passing the LazySeq gives `clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to java.lang.Number`

I am making pairs using this function

```
(def pairs  (map vector  poly-x  poly-y))
```

How do I unwrap this vector so the compiler treat will the passed argument separately

polygon signature:

```
(defn polygon
  "Create a polygonal shape with the given set of vertices.
  points is a list of x/y pairs, e.g.:

    (polygon [1 2] [3 4] [5 6])
  "
  [& points])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course apply was the way to go:

```
(apply polygon pairs)
```

Comment: Accept this to tell everybody else that the question has been properly answered.